# Invoke non-static Java method in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, interop

Invoking a static Java method in Clojure is smooth; no problem. But when I invoke a non-static method, it throws an error, although I have tried several variations for dot (.) notation, as explained in [Clojure Interop documentation](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop).

The Java class:

```
public class CljHelper {

  public void test(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
  }

}
```

The Clojure code:

```
(ns com.acme.clojure.Play
  (:import [com.acme.helpers CljHelper]))

(. CljHelper test "This is a test")
```

The error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method: test
```

This is another attempt, which makes the Java method to be executed but throws an error right after:

```
(defn add-Id
  [x]
  (let [c (CljHelper.)]
    ((.test c x))))        ;;; java.lang.NullPointerException: null in this line

(add-Id "id42")
```

The error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: Remove the outer parens `((.test c x))` - you are calling the result of test, which is nil - parens always have meaning and can not be added to make things more clear like in curly-brace-langs.

Comment: yes, you're right; there was an extra set of parens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two different issues here. In the first example you're trying to invoke a method on the class `CljHelper`. You should be calling it on the instance, not the class.

```clj
(.test (CljHelper.) "This is a test")
```

For the second example, you have an extra set of parentheses. So, you're correctly calling the method `test`, but then you are taking the result, which is null, and attempting to call that as a function. So just remove the parentheses.

```clj
(defn add-id
  [x]
  (let [c (CljHelper.)]
    (.test c x)))
```

Comment: Yep, suggested solutions for both issues work. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is the easiest way to do it.  Make a java class Calc:

```
package demo;

public class Calc {
  public int answer() {
    return 42;
  } 
}
```

and call it from Clojure:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:import [demo Calc]))

(let [c (Calc.)]                   ; construct an instance of Calc
  (println :answer (.answer c)))   ; call the instance method
```

with result:

```
:answer 42
```

You can [clone a template Clojure project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) to get started.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I have implemented your solution. The Java method is executed but it immediately throws a java.lang.NullPointerException: null.

Comment: Add your current code to the question.  You probably forgot to add the `text` after `c`

Comment: I have removed the extra set of parentheses, as commented in above answer, and it works now.